# DirectX12 root signature error while using compute shader with ConsumeStructuredBuffer

Tags: directx12

I am getting this error:  I do not have CBV, but it looks like I am forgetting to bind a CBV.

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateComputePipelineState: Root Signature doesn't match Compute Shader: Shader CBV descriptor range (BaseShaderRegister=0, NumDescriptors=1, RegisterSpace=0) is not fully bound in root signature
 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #882: CREATECOMPUTEPIPELINESTATE_CS_ROOT_SIGNATURE_MISMATCH]

the hlsl is very small..it's just add to a particle system

```
struct Particle
{
    float3 Position;
    float3 Velocity;
    float3 Acceleration;
};
float TimeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
ConsumeStructuredBuffer<Particle> gInput : register(u0);
AppendStructuredBuffer<Particle> gOutput : register(u1);
[numthreads(16, 16, 1)]
void CS()
{
// Consume a data element from the input buffer.
    Particle p = gInput.Consume();
    p.Velocity += p.Acceleration * TimeStep;
    p.Position += p.Velocity * TimeStep;
// Append normalized vector to output buffer.
    gOutput.Append(p);
}
```

And the application is

```
#include "../../Common/d3dApp.h"
#include "../../Common/UploadBuffer.h"

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;
using namespace DirectX;
using namespace DirectX::PackedVector;

#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3D12.lib")


struct Particle
{
    XMFLOAT3 Position;
    XMFLOAT3 Velocity;
    XMFLOAT3 Acceleration;
};

class ParticleAddCSApp : public D3DApp
{
public:
    ParticleAddCSApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ParticleAddCSApp(const ParticleAddCSApp& rhs) = delete;
    ParticleAddCSApp& operator=(const ParticleAddCSApp& rhs) = delete;
    ~ParticleAddCSApp();

    virtual bool Initialize()override;

private:
    virtual void OnResize()override;
    virtual void Update(const GameTimer& gt)override;
    virtual void Draw(const GameTimer& gt)override;

    void DoComputeWork();

    void BuildBuffers();
    void BuildRootSignature();
    void BuildShadersAndInputLayout();
    void BuildPSOs();

private:

    ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> mRootSignature = nullptr;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, ComPtr<ID3DBlob>> mShaders;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ComPtr<ID3D12PipelineState>> mPSOs;

    std::vector<D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC> mInputLayout;

    const int NumDataElements = 16*16;

    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> mInputBufferA = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> mInputUploadBufferA = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> mOutputBuffer = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> mOutputBuffer1 = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> mReadBackBuffer = nullptr;

};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
    PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif

    try
    {
        ParticleAddCSApp theApp(hInstance);
        if(!theApp.Initialize())
            return 0;

       // return theApp.Run();
        return 0;
    }
    catch(DxException& e)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, e.ToString().c_str(), L"HR Failed", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
}

ParticleAddCSApp::ParticleAddCSApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
    : D3DApp(hInstance)
{
}

ParticleAddCSApp::~ParticleAddCSApp()
{
    if(md3dDevice != nullptr)
        FlushCommandQueue();
}

bool ParticleAddCSApp::Initialize()
{
    if(!D3DApp::Initialize())
        return false;

    // Reset the command list to prep for initialization commands.
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Reset(mDirectCmdListAlloc.Get(), nullptr));


    BuildBuffers();
    BuildRootSignature();
    BuildShadersAndInputLayout();
    BuildPSOs();

    // Execute the initialization commands.
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Close());
    ID3D12CommandList* cmdsLists[] = { mCommandList.Get() };
    mCommandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(cmdsLists), cmdsLists);

    // Wait until initialization is complete.
    FlushCommandQueue();

    DoComputeWork();

    return true;
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::OnResize()
{
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::Update(const GameTimer& gt)
{
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::Draw(const GameTimer& gt)
{
}


void ParticleAddCSApp::DoComputeWork()
{
    // Reuse the memory associated with command recording.
    // We can only reset when the associated command lists have finished execution on the GPU.
    ThrowIfFailed(mDirectCmdListAlloc->Reset());

    // A command list can be reset after it has been added to the command queue via ExecuteCommandList.
    // Reusing the command list reuses memory.
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Reset(mDirectCmdListAlloc.Get(), mPSOs["particleAdd"].Get()));

    mCommandList->SetComputeRootSignature(mRootSignature.Get());

    mCommandList->SetComputeRootUnorderedAccessView(0, mInputBufferA->GetGPUVirtualAddress());
    mCommandList->SetComputeRootUnorderedAccessView(1, mOutputBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress());

    mCommandList->Dispatch(1, 1, 1);

    // Schedule to copy the data to the default buffer to the readback buffer.

    //D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE: The resource is used as the source in a copy operation. 
    //D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST: The resource is used as the destination in a copy operation.

    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(mOutputBuffer.Get(), 
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE));

    //We need to read the data back from the GPU after computer shader does its calculation
    //mCommandList->CopyResource(Destination: CPUData, Source: GPUData);
    mCommandList->CopyResource(mReadBackBuffer.Get(), mOutputBuffer.Get());

    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(mOutputBuffer.Get(),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS));


    // Done recording commands.
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Close());

    // Add the command list to the queue for execution.
    ID3D12CommandList* cmdsLists[] = { mCommandList.Get() };
    mCommandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(cmdsLists), cmdsLists);

    // Wait for the work to finish.
    FlushCommandQueue();

    // Map the data so we can read it on CPU.
    Particle* mappedData = nullptr;
    ThrowIfFailed(mReadBackBuffer->Map(0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&mappedData)));

    std::ofstream fout("results.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < NumDataElements; ++i)
    {
        fout << "(" << mappedData[i].Acceleration.x << ", " << mappedData[i].Acceleration.y << ", " << mappedData[i].Acceleration.z <<
            ", " << mappedData[i].Position.x << ", " << mappedData[i].Position.y << ", " << mappedData[i].Position.z <<
            ", " << mappedData[i].Velocity.x << ", " << mappedData[i].Velocity.y << ", " << mappedData[i].Velocity.z << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    mReadBackBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::BuildBuffers()
{
    // Generate some data.
    std::vector<Particle> dataA(NumDataElements);
    for(int i = 0; i < NumDataElements; ++i)
    {
        dataA[i].Acceleration = XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        dataA[i].Position = XMFLOAT3((float)i, (float)i, (float)i);
        dataA[i].Velocity = XMFLOAT3(10.0f, 10.0f, 0);
    }

    UINT64 byteSize = dataA.size()*sizeof(Particle);

    // Create some buffers to be used as SRV.
    //mInputBufferA = d3dUtil::CreateDefaultBuffer(
    //  md3dDevice.Get(),
    //  mCommandList.Get(),
    //  dataA.data(),
    //  byteSize,
    //  mInputUploadBufferA);


    // Create the actual mInputBufferA buffer resource.
    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(byteSize, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mInputBufferA)));

    // In order to copy CPU memory data into our mInputBufferA buffer, we need to create
    // an intermediate upload heap. 
    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(byteSize),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(mInputUploadBufferA.GetAddressOf())));


    // Describe the data we want to copy into the default buffer.
    D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subResourceData = {};
    subResourceData.pData = dataA.data();
    subResourceData.RowPitch = byteSize;
    subResourceData.SlicePitch = subResourceData.RowPitch;

    // Schedule to copy the data to the mInputBufferA buffer resource.  At a high level, the helper function UpdateSubresources
    // will copy the CPU memory into the intermediate upload heap.  Then, using ID3D12CommandList::CopySubresourceRegion,
    // the intermediate upload heap data will be copied to mBuffer.
    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(mInputBufferA.Get(),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST));

    UpdateSubresources(mCommandList.Get(), mInputBufferA.Get(), mInputUploadBufferA.Get(), 0, 0, 1, &subResourceData);


    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(mInputBufferA.Get(),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS));


    /*D3D12_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc;
    uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    uavDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D12_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_APPEND;
    uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = mNumElements;*/


    // Create the buffer that will be a UAV.
    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(byteSize, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mOutputBuffer)));

    //Specifies a heap used for reading back. This heap type has CPU access optimized for reading data back from the GPU, 
    //but does not experience the maximum amount of bandwidth for the GPU. This heap type is best for GPU-write-once, 
    //CPU-readable data. The CPU cache behavior is write-back, which is conducive for multiple sub-cache-line CPU reads.
    //Resources in this heap must be created with D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, and cannot be changed away from this
    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(byteSize),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mReadBackBuffer)));
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::BuildRootSignature()
{


    // Root parameter can be a table, root descriptor or root constants.
    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER slotRootParameter[2];

    // Perfomance TIP: Order from most frequent to least frequent.
    slotRootParameter[0].InitAsUnorderedAccessView(0);
    slotRootParameter[1].InitAsUnorderedAccessView(1);


    // A root signature is an array of root parameters.
    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSigDesc(2, slotRootParameter,
        0, nullptr,
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_NONE);

    // create a root signature with a single slot which points to a descriptor range consisting of a single constant buffer
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> serializedRootSig = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> errorBlob = nullptr;


    HRESULT hr = D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSigDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1,
        serializedRootSig.GetAddressOf(), errorBlob.GetAddressOf());

    if(errorBlob != nullptr)
    {
        ::OutputDebugStringA((char*)errorBlob->GetBufferPointer());
    }
    ThrowIfFailed(hr);

    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateRootSignature(
        0,
        serializedRootSig->GetBufferPointer(),
        serializedRootSig->GetBufferSize(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(mRootSignature.GetAddressOf())));
}


void ParticleAddCSApp::BuildShadersAndInputLayout()
{
    mShaders["particleAddCS"] = d3dUtil::CompileShader(L"Shaders\\ParticleAdd.hlsl", nullptr, "CS", "cs_5_1");
}

void ParticleAddCSApp::BuildPSOs()
{
    D3D12_COMPUTE_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC computePsoDesc = {};
    computePsoDesc.pRootSignature = mRootSignature.Get();
    computePsoDesc.CS =
    {
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mShaders["particleAddCS"]->GetBufferPointer()),
        mShaders["particleAddCS"]->GetBufferSize()
    };
    computePsoDesc.Flags = D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_FLAG_NONE;
    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateComputePipelineState(&computePsoDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mPSOs["particleAdd"])));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the computer shader code, I had to declare the type as "static const", otherwise this would override it from the app via constant buffer.

static const float TimeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;